# "IS" operator Delphi in CBuilder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

In Delphi, I wrote the following code to identify a Graphic is a TBitmap:

```
if aImage.Picture.Graphic is TBitmap then 
  ...
```

In C ++ Builder I wrote the following code:

```
if (dynamic_cast<Image1->Picture->Graphic>(TBitmap) != 0) 
    ....
```

But it does not work. How do C ++ Builder to do the same check done in Delphi?

Comment: I formatted your code and corrected the syntax error. I think you should do better than "it does not work". Can you be precise about what you expect to happen, and what does happen?

Comment: Errata: The correct code is `if aImage.Picture.Graphic is TBitmap`

Comment: I reverted your destructive edit.

Comment: *it does not work* is not a meaningful problem description.  In what way does it *not work*? Do you get a compiler error? If so, what does that error say? Do you get a  runtime error? If so, what's the error message? You need to be specific. You know **precisely** what *it does not work* means, but we don't, and you have the details. There's no excuse for not providing them to us in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be

```
if (dynamic_cast<TBitmap*>(Image1->Picture->Graphic) != 0) 
    ....
```

or

```
if (dynamic_cast<TBitmap*>(Image1->Picture->Graphic) != nullptr) 
    ....
```

or

```
if (dynamic_cast<TBitmap*>(Image1->Picture->Graphic)) 
    ....
```

or

```
TBitmap* bitmap = dynamic_cast<TBitmap*>(Image1->Picture->Graphic);
if (bitmap)
{
    .... 
    // do stuff with bitmap
}
```

These are all equivalent, you can choose whichever you prefer.

The `dynamic_cast` operator is documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dynamic_cast_(C%2B%2B_Type_Cast_Operator)

Comment: @alexandrecrt: If you later on use casts of `aImage.Picture.Graphic` to `TBitmap` in your Delphi code, you should probably save the result of `dynamic_cast` in a variable and use that instead in C++.